# usermod command heavily increasing Docker container size

Tags: docker

I'm creating a docker container using image `nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu16.04`. The I used to run it is essentially:

```
docker run \
    --name <my_container_name> \
    -it \
    --user root \
    --workdir / \
    --net host \
    --env http_proxy=http://127.0.15.1:3128/ \
    --env https_proxy=http://127.0.15.1:3128/ \
    --env ftp_proxy=http://127.0.15.1:3128/ \
    nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu16.04
```

The proxy changes are required for another reason. Right after creating it, my container has size around 30KB. Within the container I need to run the `usermod` command to change my username within the container to my username in the host machine. First I changed the group with:

`groupmod -g 1712325121 -n <my_username> user`

`user` is the username within the container. 1712325121 is the group ID in the host machine, as returned by `id <my_username>`.

After `groupmod`, I run `usermod` as:

`usermod -d /home/<my_username> -m -u 1712506013 -l <my_username> user`

Where 1712506013 is the id of my user in the host machine as returned by `id <my_username>`.

My issue is that, right after running `usermod`, the size of my container grows from around 30KB to a whooping 555GB. What is the reason for such growth, and how can I fix it?

Comment: 50 kB for a cuda-based docker container is not likely, just as a 555GB size. How are you measuring the size ?

Comment: I'm using `docker system df -v` to check container size. But I did commit an image based on the container after running `usermod`, and the commited image also had ~550GB size. About the base container, i think the 50kB might be either because it is a modification of the container I mentioned, or because the layer sharing among containers

Answer (score 3):

For anyone curious about this problem, it is due to the following issue: https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/issues/2287

The size of the two files in question:

```
root@dde99a5ac91f:/var/log# ls -alh
total 592K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root 4.0K Sep  3 15:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root 4.0K Nov  8  2019 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  52G Sep 11 14:48 faillog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   utmp 466G Sep 11 14:48 lastlog
```

Since my user ID is huge, these files end up being very large.

Answer (score 0):

With the copy-on-write filesystem, any change to a file inside the container triggers a copy of the entire file. And the usermod command will modify the files owned by the old uid to have the new uid. Each of these uid changes will copy the entire file, so if that user owned over 500GB of files in the image, you have now copied all of those files into the container filesystem.

Comment: Hmm, that explains the issue, but there is still a question. This size change happens with my ID, which comes from LDAP. But for a colleague of mine, who has an ID which is not from LDAP, the container size remains the same after `usermod`, even though the owner of the files within the container is also different from his. Any idea why?

Comment: Did the UID change from what was in the image for your colleague?

Comment: As far as he told me, it did. The UID used to create the image is `1000`, and his UID is `1003`. GIDs are different as well. For contrast, as I mentioned in my original question, my UID is `1712506013`. That is the weird part, it seems the difference is only in the value of the UID itself

Comment: Would need to see a [mcve] of the colleague's environment to help further. To answer your original question a uid change with an overlay filesystem will trigger a copy of the entire file. Avoid those if possible. E.g. use named volumes to avoid the need to match UID's to the host.

Comment: My colleague just found out the reason. It is related to this issue: https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/issues/2287. Essentially, two files are the culprits: `/var/log/lastlog` and  `/var/log/faillog`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Postgresql from RPMs in a container and I faced the same issue. Installing with RPMs creates user *postgres*. The fix was to create user beforehand using *useradd* command. *useradd* command has an option "*-l , -no-log-init*" with description "*do not add the user to the lastlog and faillog databases*". With that I could create the user with specific --uid and --gid.